# Using a public void onComplete (File outfile) method inside of a Android Fragment

Tags: java, android

I am using the following method to generate a file on a users device then email it to me.

```
new ActivityDumpUtil(FragmentRequestIcons.this, outfile, new ActivityDumpUtil.ActivityDumpCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete (File outfile) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    intent.setType("text/plain");
                    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(outfile);
                    intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
                    intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { "************" });
                    intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Icon Support");
                    intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "I am using " + Build.DEVICE + " with Android version " + Build.VERSION.RELEASE + " on " + getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send eMail.."));
                    finish();
                }
            })
```

I recently had this in an Activity but am wanting it in a fragment now because im using Androids navigation drawer.

Of course the finish() won't work in a fragment. How can i make this work from my fragment?

Answer (score 0):

Make the class [serializable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html) and put it with the intent.

To make your class serializable:

```
class yourClass implements Serializable{}
```

To put it with your intent:

```
intent.putExtra("The Class", this);
```

To get the class out of the intent(use this in your fragment):

```
yourClass yc = (yourClass) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("The Class");
yc.finish()//use this whenever you want
```

Comment: How would i go about that?

Comment: see edit. But i think it is easyer to make your fragment a fragmentActivity. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html

Comment: I thought about that, but im using navigation drawer. If i do that i will have to reload the navigation drawer. I went that way to start with but keeping everything in fragments seemed to be the way to go. I will try your updated answer. Thank you for the response

Comment: If you call your fragment with an intent, you should be able to call getIntent in your fragment.